# Show a number line based on the given string

Tags: java

I am stuck in my project where we have to show a string of line in the number line scale so later we can delete or add characters to that string. I am not sure how to print out the scale in 5s based on the length of the string.

Ex:

```
0    5   10   15   20 
|----+----|----+----|-
This is the first line
```

Then, the user will choose the characters they want to delete from the string using from position and to position. It will show what position the user chose from the string and delete.

Ex:

```
from position: 12
to position: 18

0    5   10   15   20 
|----+----|----+----|-
This is the first line
            ^^^^^^^ --> // this will be deleted
y/n: y
 0    5   10   15
|----+----|----+
This is the ine
```

I was able to delete the characters but I do not know how to show the number line based on a string. Here is my code so far:

```
 public void showNumberLine(String line) 
    {
        int lineCount = line.length(); // getting the length of the string being passed in
        String numberLine = "";

        for(int i = 0; i <= lineCount; i++) // 
        {

                numberLine = "" + i;
                System.out.println("|----+----|----+----|-");

        }
    }

public void deleteSubString()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        showNumberLine(textOfLine); // this will print out then number line and the line

        System.out.print("from position: ");
        int fromIndex = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("to position: ");
        int toIndex = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(fromIndex < 0 || fromIndex > numOfChar || toIndex < 0 || toIndex > numOfChar)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot delete at the given index: Index Out of Bounds");
        }

        /*
         * Create a new number line where it shows what is going to be deleted
         */
        String newLineOfString = textOfLine.substring(fromIndex, toIndex);
        textOfLine = textOfLine.replace(newLineOfString, "");
        System.out.println(newLineOfString);

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to implement a method `printScale` or something like that which takes a `String` or an `int` as argument and prints these two lines for you.

You sad you already can remove the characters so if you have a `String` with the value `"This is the ine"` as you showed in your example you could call the method like this:

`printScale(myNewString.length());`

This method could look something like this (not perfect but works):

```
public void printLine(int amountOfCharacters) {
    StringBuilder lineNumber = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder lineScaleSymbols = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfCharacters; i++) {
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            if (i < 10) {
                lineNumber.append(i);
            } else {
                lineNumber.insert(i -1, i);
            }
            lineScaleSymbols.append('|');
        } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            if (i < 10) {
                lineNumber.append(i);
            } else {
                lineNumber.insert(i -1, i);
            }
            lineScaleSymbols.append('+');
        } else {
            lineNumber.append(' ');
            lineScaleSymbols.append('-');
        }
    }

    System.out.println(lineNumber.toString());
    System.out.println(lineScaleSymbols.toString());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with your `showNumberLine` method.

Let's outline exactly what you need to do:

- determine the length of the string
- generate a number line of the same length as the string

  - every character ending with `0` will be the special character `|`
  - every character ending in `5` will be the special character `+`
  - every other character will be `-`

You could make your loop like this, using the modulus operator to determine which character to write:

```
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
    if(i % 10 == 0) {
        // the number is divisible by 10 (ends in zero)
        System.out.print("|");
    } else if(i % 5 == 0 && i % 10 != 0) {
        // the number is divisible by 5 and not divisible by 10 (ends in 5)
        System.out.print("+");
    } else {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
|----+----|----+----|----+----|----+----|---
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

You'll need some more code to write out the digits (0, 5, 10, 15) above the number line, I'll leave that to you. It will be similar logic but there are subtle issues to consider as the length of the numbers is 1 character, then 2 characters, then 3 characters as they increase (0, 5, 10, 15, ... 100, 105). At some point you'll have to stop as the numbers won't fit in the space.